# Sending a QML TypedArray to C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, typed-arrays

Given the following QML code:

```
property var arr: new Float64Array(1000);
function foo() {
  someCPPObject.operation(arr);
}
```

What is the type that I must use in my C++ method, to be able to use that array ? (without any copying of the underlying data)

TypedArrays are marked as supported, and indeed editing them from QML code works: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42097 but I cannot find anything in the docs about how to use them from C++.

Comment: `QList<qreal>` and `QVariantList` are the only types mentioned that can be converted/exchanged from QML to C++ for arrays , if they dont work .. chances to get that without copying are low  [Conversion Between Qt and JavaScript Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#conversion-between-qt-and-javascript-types)

Comment: of course and `QJsonArray`